# Visual Studio Publish gives different binaries to build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I usually deploy my web application by right clicking on the app and selecting the publish option. VS copies everything to a local file system folder then I zip it up and copy it to the web server.

For some reason when I publish my branch the binary in the publish folder is different from the binary in the local build folder. It's as if it's building different code.

Both the local build and the publish are using Debug (Any CPU) configuration.

Here's a screenshot of the decompiled assemblies.

This first one is the one from the project bin folder and runs perfectly.
[image: This is the built binary from the bin folder]

This one is from the publish folder and as you can see it contains some lines which aren't in the other build.
[image: This is the binary from the publish folder. Totally different]

This particular class doesn't have any `#IF DEBUG` pragmas in it.

I've tried clearing out the bin and obj folders with no success.

Does Visual Studio have a cached copy of all the code somewhere that it uses to do the publish build that I can clear out?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure you have Debug configuration enabled in Publish settings? Publish settings override current Visual Studio project configuration.
   [image]
2. Having Debug publish configuration enabled, publishing applies the `Web.Debug.config` transformations over `Web.config`, while local build ignores `Web.Debug.config`. As I see, you miss the `NewJobRegisteredObject` in published assembly, you may have `xdt:Replace` section in `Web.Debug.config` removing object registration.